# SQL Numeric to Date (with an exception)

Tags: sql, datetime, numeric

I have a SQL Query in which I'm querying specific data from a table with the dates stored in a Numeric Column. I'm using the below query to convert the Numeric date to an actual date, but I have instances where the Numeric Value is 0, meaning that i.e. the Start Date is October 31, 2013, and there is no End Date, meaning that 0 is an open record. Is there a way I can add an error-catch where if the value is 0, just return either a 0 or 'Open' and continue?

```
 SELECT WMACCT# as 'Account #', CONVERT(Date, CONVERT(Varchar(8),OPENDT),104)
 as 'Open Date',

 CONVERT(Date, CONVERT(Varchar(8),CLDT),104)as 'Close Date'From 
 server.server
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CASE WHEN to set the values you want when the date is 0 and do what you were doing for the remaining values:

```
SELECT WMACCT# AS 'Account #',
  CASE 
    WHEN OPENDT = 0 THEN '2013-10-31'
        ELSE CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), OPENDT), 104)
    END AS 'Open Date',
  CASE 
    WHEN DATE = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CLDT), 104)
    END AS 'Close Date'
FROM SERVER.SERVER
```

Comment: This is perfect! I edited it to what I needed, and it's great! I tried to upvote/mark as best answer, but I don't have the rep for it

Comment: @Dakota. Glad it worked :). You can't upvote until 15 rep. To accept it, you have to wait 15 minutes from when you posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no "error-catch".

You could use an expression to test for the zero value, and bypass the datatype conversion:
For example:

```
CASE WHEN OPENDT = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(Date, CONVERT(Varchar(8),OPENDT),104) END
```

You could return NULL. To have the expression return a `'0'` or `'Open'`, that wouldn't match the datatype of DATE returned by the ELSE.  A column in a resultset has to have a datatype, it can't return a DATE on some rows, and a VARCHAR on other rows.